# ERROR: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'order_id'"

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa

```
List<ACOrders> acOrders = ordersRepo.findAllByOrderId(44L);
```

```
@Repository
public interface ACOrdersRepository extends JpaRepository<ACOrders, Long> {

    ACOrders findByOrderId(Long orderId);

}
```

I am using mssql as database my property files are as below:

```
#mssql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://<ip>:1433;database=<database>
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by putting two additional property in my application.property file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```